# LINQ to SQL Cannot create database [Schema Permissions]

Tags: c#, linq, sql-server-2005, linq-to-sql, integration-testing

For some integration tests I want to use LINQ to SQL to drop/re-create the test database. I've had this working fine before, however in this project the database is split up into several schemas.

When I try to run the `ctx.CreateDatabase()` command I'm getting this exception:

> The specified schema name "xyz" either
>   does not exist or you do not have
>   permission to use it.

The login I'm using to do this has the role `dbcreator` - Does it need further permissions? Surely a login with persmissions to create a database should be able to create everything contained in that database also?

### Update:

Since it looks like there isn't a solution to this problem using LINQtoSQL, does anyone have recommendations of any similiar tools to generate a db that are preferably free? Ideally I don't want to have to muck about hand writing sql build scripts.

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio can script out an entire database.  Right-click on a database, choose Tasks, and then choose "Generate Scripts".  For more features you probably want to consider a commercial solution, such as SQL Compare http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Compare/index.htm .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I've read, the CreateDatabase() method is limited in what it can reproduce of the original database.  It won't recreate things like triggers and check constraints, and I'm guessing it doesn't create custom schemas either.  You may want to look into creating the database using a [SQL Server .mdf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399420.aspx) file instead to work around this issue.  See [this blog entry](http://csainty.blogspot.com/2008/02/linq-to-sql-be-careful-of.html) for more details on some of the limitations of CreateDatabase().

Answer (score 1):

I generally do this sort of work in NAnt to create, initialize the database, create users, add logins, etc....and also roll back capabilities.  I have written on this topic quite a bit if you are interested:

[Build automation with NAnt](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Building-a-StackOverflow-inspired-Knowledge-Exchange-Build-automation-with-NAnt.aspx)

[Continuous integration with CruiseControl.NET](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Building-a-StackOverflow-inspired-Knowledge-Exchange-Continuous-integration-with-CruiseControl-NET.aspx)

I will have to see if I can get LINQ to SQL to work in the way you are trying to use it...that sounds like what we used to do with NHibernate.

Answer (score 1):

The dbcreator fixed server role grants you the permission to create a database. If you create a database, you are the dbo of said database and as dbo you have absolute power in the database, includding the power to create, alter and drop any schema and any object contained in any schema.

the problem with LINQ's CreateDatabase() is not permission, is code quality. The generated SQL code simply does not create the needed schema, so the Create table statements fail because the schema does not exist.

Your best choice, if you can afford it, is to add a [VSTS Database Edition GDR R2](http://blogs.msdn.com/gertd/archive/2008/06/03/vsts-2008-database-edition-gdr-june-ctp.aspx) project to your solution and declare all your database objects in the Database Edition project (part of your solution). You'll be also getting the added benefit of storing all your database objects in a proper source control solution. The output of the Database project would be a .dbschema file containing the definition of your database. At deployment time (test or real) you would run the VSDBCMD [Deployment and Schema Import tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd193283.aspx) to import your .dbschema into the target server. The tool is capable of doing initial deployment of your schema, as well as further upgrades (deploy only differences). The VSDB solution would allow you to controll all your database objects: tables, indexes, views, schemas, field contraints, table constraints, triggers, procedures, users, permissions, logins etc etc. It really covers *all* the objects that can be defined in SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

Actually LINQ to SQL does support schemas, but not every Sql Server edition does. To enable `CreateDatabase()` to generate them the `DataContext` must be aware that the target database does support them. It can be done by setting the provider on the `DataContext`:

```
[Provider(typeof(Sql2008Provider))]
public class CustomDataContext : DataContext {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your user also requires `db_dlladmin` for that database.

Comment: The database may not necessarily exist at any given time, i can't map permissions to it.

Answer (score 0):

I would definately look at Entity Framework, which I am beginning to look into these days. It's an OR/M, and will most definately suit your needs, and alot more once the next version is released.

Entity Framework is also a brain-child of Microsoft and can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427(VS.80).aspx

One thing to remember between LINQ to SQL and LINQ to Entities is that you are programming against a model, and not the database.